# Logistic Regression's ROC Goes Abnormal

Tags: r, logistic-regression, roc

Currently, I'm learning about logistic regression and LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) classification. I'm trying to generate the data differently to learn logistic regression and LDA behavior. 

Here is the data visualization of 2-dimensional predictors with class plotted as color:
[image: This is the link to see the visualization]

Here is my code:

```html
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)

set.seed(1)

a <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(0.4,0,0,0.4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
b <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(10,0,0,10), nrow = 2, ncol =2 ))

#I want to make sure b1 separated from a
b1 <- b[sqrt(b[,1]^2 + b[,2]^2) > 4,]

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(a,b1))
names(df) <- c('x','y')
labelA <- rep('A', nrow(a))
labelB <- rep('B', nrow(b1))
#Put the label column to the data frame
df$labs <- c(labelA,labelB)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = labs)) + geom_point()

prd <- glm(as.factor(labs) ~ x + y, family = binomial('probit'), data = df)
prd_score <- predict(prd, type = 'response')
plot(roc(df$labs,prd_score))
auc(roc(df$labs,prd_score))
```

And this is the roc curve plot
[image: Weird ROC here]

It's really frustrating because I couldn't find any mistake in my code that generates this kind of problem. Can anyone help me to point out any mistake in my code that generates this weird kind of ROC or any explanation on why the ROC could become weird like that? 

NB: Please assume that the generated data set above is the training data and I want to predict the training data again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mistake in your code.

Your dataset is a typical example that cannot be separated with a linear combination of features. Therefore linear classification method such as logistic regression or LDA won't help you here. This is why your ROC curve looks "weird", but it's totally normal and only telling you that your model fails to separate the data.

You need to investigate non-linear classification techniques. Given the radial distribution of the data, I can imagine that support vector machines (SVM) with a radial basis kernel could do the trick.

```
require(e1071)

# We need a numeric label for SVM regression
labelA <- rep(0, nrow(a))
labelB <- rep(1, nrow(b1))
df$labsNum <- c(labelA,labelB)

# We create a radial basis model
svm_prd <- svm(labsNum ~ x + y, data = df, kernel = "radial", type = "eps-regression")
svm_score <- predict(svm_prd)
plot(roc(df$labs,prd_score))
auc(roc(df$labs,prd_score))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Yes, the score is not separating the classes at all. I also figured that there's an extreme sensitivity and specificity trade-off when we move the threshold for class determination. That's why the ROC curve will be looked like s-shape. Yap! SVM with radial basis will definitely work well. Also, I guess that even simple non-parametric method will help to classify this kind of classification problem (i.e. k-NN).

Comment: k-NN falls in the class of non-linear classifiers and should perform fine here. But It has nothing to do whether it is parametric or not.